# Overlaying two ggplot facet_wrap histograms

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

So I have two histogram plots I can do one at a time. The result using the following code gives a 2 row x 3 col facet plot for six different histograms:

```
ggplot(data) +
    aes(x=values) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth=2, fill='blue', alpha=0.3, color="black", aes(y=(..count..)*100/(sum(..count..)/6))) +
    facet_wrap(~ model_f, ncol = 3)
```

Here the `aes(y...)` just gives the percentage instead of counts.

As stated, I have two of this 6 facet_wrap plot, which I now which to combine to show that one is more shifted than the other. 
In addition, the data size is not the same, so for one I have:

```
# A tibble: 5,988 x 5
   values ID   structure   model   model_f
   <dbl> <chr>     <chr>   <chr>    <fctr>
 1     6     1    bone       qua   Model I
 2     7     1    bone       liu  Model II
 3    20     1    bone       dav Model III
 4     3     1    bone       ema  Model IV
 5     3     1    bone       tho   Model V
 6     4     1    bone      ranc  Model VI
 7     3     2    bone       qua   Model I
 8     5     2    bone       liu  Model II
 9    18     2    bone       dav Model III
10     2     2    bone       ema  Model IV
# ... with 5,978 more rows
```

And the other:

```
# A tibble: 954 x 5
    values  ID structure   model   model_f
   <dbl>  <chr>     <chr>   <chr>    <fctr>
 1     9     01    bone       qua   Model I
 2     8     01    bone       liu  Model II
 3    22     01    bone       dav Model III
 4     6     01    bone       ema  Model IV
 5     5     01    bone       tho   Model V
 6     9     01    bone       ran  Model VI
 7    12     02    bone       qua   Model I
 8    11     02    bone       liu  Model II
 9    24     02    bone       dav Model III
10     9     02    bone       ema  Model IV
# ... with 944 more rows
```

So they are not the same size, the ID's are not the same (data not related), but still, I wish to merge the histograms in order to see the difference between the data.

I thought this might do the trick:

```
ggplot() +
    geom_histogram(data=data1, aes(x=values), binwidth=1, fill='blue', alpha=0.3, color="black", aes(y=(..count..)*100/(sum(..count..)/6))) +
    geom_histogram(data=data2, aes(x=values), binwidth=1, fill='blue', alpha=0.3, color="black", aes(y=(..count..)*100/(sum(..count..)/6))) +
    facet_wrap(~ model_f, ncol = 3)
```

However, that didn't do much.

So now I'm stuck. Is this possible to do, or...?

Comment: Have you considered stacking the datasets, then doing a `facet_wrap` with two variables?

Comment: But wouldn't I get into a problem with two variables ? The only difference between the data sets is the IDs. But they are different for each data set, and ranges from 1-~1000 for one data set to 1-~160 for the other data set.

Comment: For the purposes of plotting I don't think so. I don't think you rely on the IDs at all for plots do you?

Comment: I don't no. But which other variable would distinguish the two data sets in the facet_wrap ? Or maybe I'm just not aware of how it works with two variables.

Comment: You could try something like `rbind(cbind(data1, df = "1"), cbind(data2, df = "2"))`. Then your other facet would be `df`

Comment: Hmmm, if I write: <!-- df_full <- rbind(cbind(data1, df = "1"), cbind(data2, df = "2"))

ggplot(df_full, aes(values, fill = df)) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth=2, fill='blue',
                   alpha=0.3, color="black",
                   aes(y=(..count..)*100/(sum(..count..)/6)),
                   position = 'identity') +
    facet_wrap( ~ model_f + df, ncol = 3) --> I get 12 plots, instead of 6, and one is weirdly scaled compared to the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my crack at this, based on the builtin dataset `iris` (since you did not provide reproducible data). To create the smaller, shifted dataset, I am using `dplyr` to keep the first 20 rows from each species and add 1 to the Sepal length for each observation:

```
smallIris <-
  iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  slice(1:20) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Sepal.Length = Sepal.Length + 1)
```

Your code at the end gets you close, but you did not specify different colors for the two histograms. If you set the `fill` differently for each, you will get them to show up differently. You could either set this directly (e.g., change "blue" to "red" in one of them) or by setting a name within `aes`. Setting it in `aes` has the advantage of creating (and labeling) a legend:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(data=iris
                 , aes(x=Sepal.Length
                       , fill = "Big"
                       , y=(..count..)*100/(sum(..count..)))
                 , alpha=0.3) +
  geom_histogram(data=smallIris
                 , aes(x=Sepal.Length
                       , fill = "Small"
                       , y=(..count..)*100/(sum(..count..)))
                 , alpha=0.3) +
  facet_wrap(~Species)
```

Creates this:

[image]

However, I tend to dislike the look of overlapping histograms, so I would prefer to use a density plot. You can do it just like the above (just change the `geom_histogram`), but I think you get a bit more control (and the ability to expand this to more than two groups) by stacking the data. Again, this uses `dplyr` to stitch the two datasets together:

```
bigIris <-
  bind_rows(
    small = smallIris
    , big = iris
    , .id = "Source"
  )
```

Then, you can create the plot relatively easily:

```
bigIris %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, col = Source)) +
  geom_line(stat = "density") +
  facet_wrap(~Species)
```

creates:

[image]