# Overlaying two quick plot all variables from several data frames

Tags: r

I have uploaded a datafame and done a quick plot of all variables using:

```
df %>%
  keep(is.numeric) %>% 
  gather() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value)) +
  facet_wrap(~ key, scales = "free") +
  geom_histogram()
```

Reference: https://drsimonj.svbtle.com/quick-plot-of-all-variables

I have split this data frame into two data frames based on a binary variable (in my case, Smoker/Non-smoker) in one of the columns. I would like to perform the same quick plot of all variables but have overlayed, different coloured histograms for each of the new data frames (to see if they differ significantly).

I found the following:

[Overlaying two ggplot facet_wrap histograms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47596357/overlaying-two-ggplot-facet-wrap-histograms)

But it only does the facet_wrap over a single variable. Is there a way to do this by filtering the gathered data frame by the binary value something like:

```
df %>%
  keep(is.numeric) %>% 
  gather() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value)) +
  facet_wrap(~ key, scales = "free") +
  geom_histogram(subset(df,Smoker==1), fill = "Red", alpha=0.3) +
  geom_histogram(subset(df,Smoker==2), fill = "Blue", alpha=0.3)
```

Idea would be to overlay the following:

```
df_s %>%
  keep(is.numeric) %>% 
  gather() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value)) +
  facet_wrap(~ key, scales = "free") +
  geom_histogram(fill = "Red", alpha=0.3) 

df_ns %>%
  keep(is.numeric) %>% 
  gather() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value)) +
  facet_wrap(~ key, scales = "free") +
  geom_histogram(fill = "Blue", alpha=0.3)
```

I could do this will a loop but would like to do it with the df key-value pairs if possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
    df %>% 
      keep(is.numeric) %>% # you may need to remove this as smoker will need to be factor for grouping to work
      tidyr::gather(key,value, -Smoker) %>% #- preserve smoker and use to colour
      ggplot(aes(value, fill = Smoker)) +
      facet_wrap(~ key, scales = "free") +
      geom_histogram(alpha = 0.30) +
      scale_fill_manual(values = c("red","blue"))
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks! Got it working with one correction: geom_histogram(alpha = 0.30, stat = "count")